# mounting a disk to GCP Slurm cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mount, nfs, google-cloud-filestore

I created an slurm cluster on GCP following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-slurm-cluster-compute-engine. 
I also mount a filestore instance to the vm's in the slurm cluster using `mount` (into the "login" and "controller"). The jobs I am trying to run in the cluster read files located in the mounted disk, but it seems that these files are not readable by SLURM. e.g.

```
> cat ja.sh

#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o tmp.out
#SBATCH -e tmp.error
#SBATCH -n 8
#SBATCH --mem=6G 
 

storage_file=/mnt/my_filestore_disk/file.bam

python3 my_script.py $storage_file

> sbatch ja.sh
> cat tmp.error
Error $storage_file does not exist
```

The storage file is mounted on the /mnt directory and I changed the permission for the folders and files `sudo chmod 755`. The scripts `my_script.py, ja.sh` are located in the /home directory. If I run these scripts from the /mnt directory I get no output at all.  Is there any insight as to why I am getting this error? 
I am able to read these files from the /home directory and even through python without any error:

```
$ python3
> import os
> os.path.exists("/mnt/my_filestore_disk/file.bam")
True
> import pysam
> s = pysam.Samfile("/mnt/my_filestore_disk/file.bam")
```

Comment: Why are you testing with different file names `file.txt` and `file.bam`. Your script is using `file.txt` and your Python example is using `file.bam`.

Comment: My bad, fixed now